# Arcade-get 4 nearest addresses from point feature

Tags: popup, arcade

I used the below code to get the nearest one location from `$feature`, but I'm looking now to get nearest 4 records from `$feature`.

I tried with json object, arrayList, but having syntax errors. Not sure about the limitations of customization in Arcade.

```
var searchDist = 6000;
var storeAddress = Intersects(FeatureSetById($map, "storeAddressFeaturelayer_2246"), Buffer( $feature, searchDist, "meters"));
var cnt = Count(storeAddress); 
var x=0;
var nearestaddress;
var neardistance=0;
var addressDist=0;

for (var f in storeAddress {
  addressDist = Round(Distance(f, $feature, "meters"),3);
 if(x==0){
     neardistance=addressDist;
     nearestaddress = f.Address+",  "+f.PhoneNumber;
  }
 if(neardistance>addressDist && x==1){
     neardistance=addressDist;
     nearestaddress = f.Address +",  "+f.PhoneNumber;
  }
  x=1;
 }

return nearestaddress;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this way,it may help other

```
var parcel = $feature;
    var searchDist = 200;
    var storeAddress = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map,"Parcels_And_Buildings - Tax Parcels"), Buffer( $feature, searchDist, "meters"));
    var cnt = Count(storeAddress);
    Console(cnt);

    var dct = {};
    for (var address in storeAddress) {
        var addressDist = Round(Distance(address, $feature, "meters"), 3);
        var key = Text(addressDist, "000.000");
        Console(key);
        //address.Address + ",  " + address.PhoneNumber;
        var val = address.SITEADDRESS + ",  " + address.PARCELID + " (" + addressDist + "m)";
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (HasKey(dct, key)) {
                key += Text(i);
            } else {
                // skip;
            }
        }
        dct[key] = val;
    }

    var result = "";
    var mx = Min([cnt, 4]);
    var i = 0;
    for (var key in dct) {
        if (i < mx) {
            var val = dct[key];
            result += val + TextFormatting.NewLine;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    return result
```